# Will std::move() upon object construction in return statement help or prevent RVO?

Tags: c++, rvo, stdmove

Due to widely ranging responses from the community, I am asking this in hopes to debunk implementation-specific responses from stack-overflow users.

Which of these is best-practice (offers greatest optimization)?

```
// version 1
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  return MyObject();
}

// version 2
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  return std::move(MyObject());
}

// version 3
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  auto obj = MyObject()
  return obj;
}

// version 4
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  auto obj = MyObject()
  return std::move(obj);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you to Yakk, for the direct, respectful answer. [accepted answer]

Comment: "Widely ranging responses from the community" - examples? That this is bad in consensus AFAIK.

Comment: You missed the one I like: `return {};`

Comment: "offers greatest optimization" is inherently an implementation-specific question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// version 1
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  return MyObject();
}
```

In C++03 this requires `MyObject` by copyable.  At runtime, no copy will be made using any "real" compiler with reasonable settings as the standard permits elision here.

In C++11 or 14 it requires the object be movable or copyable.  Elision remains; no move or copy is done.

In C++17 there is no move or copy here to elide.

In every case, in practice, `MyObject` is directly constructed in the return value.

```
// version 2
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  return std::move(MyObject());
}
```

This is invalid in C++03.

In C++11 and beyond, `MyObject` is moved into the return value.  The move must occur at runtime (barring as-if elimination).

```
// version 3
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  auto obj = MyObject();
  return obj;
}
```

Identical to version 1, except C++17 behaves like C++11/14.  In addition, the elision here is more fragile; seemingly innocuous changes could force the compiler to actually move `obj`.

Theoretically 2 moves are elided here in C++11/14/17 (and 2 copies in C++03).  The first elision is safe, the second fragile.

```
// version 4
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  auto obj = MyObject();
  return std::move(obj);
}
```

In practice this behaves just like version 2.  An extra move (copy in C++03) occurs in constructing `obj` but it is elided, so nothing happens at runtime.

Elision permits the elimination of side effects of the copy/move; the objects lifetimes are merged into one object, and the move/copy is eliminated.  The constructor still has to exist, it is just never called.

## Answer

Both 1 and 3 will compile to identical runtime code.  3 is slightly more fragile.

Both 2 and 4 compile to identical runtime code.  It should never be faster than 1/3, but if the move can be eliminated by the compiler proving not doing it is the same as-if doing it, it could compile to the same runtime code as 1/3.  This is far from guaranteed, and extremely fragile.

So `1>=3>=2>=4` is the order of faster to slower in practice, where "more fragile" code that is otherwise the same speed is `<=`.

As an example of a case that could make 3 slower than 1, if you had an if statement:

```
// version 3 - modified
MyObject Widget::GetSomething() {
  auto obj = MyObject();
  if (err()) return MyObject("err");
  return obj;
}
```

suddenly many compilers will be forced to move `obj` into the return value instead of eliding `obj` and the return value together.